# How can I get double(or bytes) data through PQgetvalue in an efficient way?

Tags: c++, c, database, postgresql, bytea

I create a table with 3 columns: `int8`, `double` and `bytea`. When query a row of data, I use PQgetvalue to get each column value in a row.  But PQgetvalue return a char*, I have to convert text value to corresponding type, like atoi or strtod etc.

Is there is a more efficient way to get actual data, avoid converting data every time?

Comment: Use memcpy, on the source the address of double, then the destination as a char array of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much overhead in converting a `char *` to a number.  But you can use binary mode by calling `PQexecParams` with 1 as the last argument.

To retrieve binary data, you have to use `PQgetlength` and `PQgetisnull` to get size and NULLness of the datum. Also, the data will be in the binary format used by the database server, so the representation of a `double` could be different if both machines have a different hardware architecture (although IEEE is used pretty much everywhere).

Comment: I have think about using binary mode.  But according to official document, The binary representation of INT4 is in network byte order ( maybe double type is the same), it is complicated, especially deal with double type. 

Thanks for the advice, though.  I will try both way to see the actual query speed.

Answer (score 1):

Given these functions:

`PQgetvalue`:

```c
char *PQgetvalue(const PGresult *res,
                 int row_number,
                 int column_number);
```

[`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

```c
#include <string.h>
void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);
```

You extract a `double` like this:

```c
double dest;

memcpy(&dest, PQgetvalue(...), sizeof dest);
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I changed from `double` to `int64_t` because of the confusing _"int64 double bytes"_ - I've asked for clarification under the question

Comment: I think some information got lost by editing the question. I have tried to set it right.

Comment: We should consider network byte order when using binary mode

Comment: @shalow If the postgres internals don't take care of this already, then yes. But then again, if that's the case, you don't even know that the `double` is in IEEE-754 format (or whatever your local format is) at all.